# How to display each row calculate date according to the duration of days in Sql

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables which one table has Start Date and the other table has duration. The tables values will be as below

### Tour

```
TourID  | StartDate | Tour Name     
  1     | 2016/5/10 | example name  
  2     | 2016/3/20 | Tour 2
```

PlaceTrip

```
TripID   | Place ID   | Duration(days) | TourID
  1      |     1      |  5             | 1
  2      |     2      |  7             | 1
  3      |     3      |  2             | 1 
  4      |     1      |  10            | 2 
  5      |     2      |  4             | 2
```

Expected/wanted query result is the Date + Duration = Arrive Date

```
 TourID | PlacesID | Arrive Date 
   1    |    1     |   2016/5/15
   1    |    2     |   2016/5/22 <-- this date will start from 2016/5/15 instead of 2016/5/10
   1    |    3     |   2016/5/24
   2    |    1     |   2016/3/30
   2    |    2     |   2016/4/1
```

Comment: What specific version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Alex Sql server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to give you an accumulated duration:

```
SELECT TourID, TripID, PlaceID, Duration, SUM(Duration) OVER( PARTITION BY TripID ORDER BY PlaceID ) AS CumulativeDuration
FROM PlaceTrip
```

Then all you need to do is join the above to Tour table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TourID, TripID, PlaceID, Duration, SUM(Duration) OVER( PARTITION BY TripID ORDER BY PlaceID ) AS CumulativeDuration
    FROM PlaceTrip ) AS PTCD
INNER JOIN Tour AS T ON PTCD.TourID = T.TourID
```

You need to use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function to calculate "Arrive Date" by adding "CumulativeDuration" to StartDate

Comment: hi! thank you very much with the answer. i managed to get the culmulativeDuration. However, it also display all other information that i didnt request for. IS there any way to eliminate it?

Comment: Nvm. please ignore my previous comment which is silly. I found out that u did select *

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a sub-query which gets all the durations.

1) Get the data of all previous rows (in your case the Place ID I assume) and sum them up.

2) Add the sum for each row (place id) to the initial start date (2016/5/10) with the dateadd function.

Here an example (to complete by yourself):

```
    select CurrentPlace.PlaceID,
    sum(CurrentPlace.Duration) as TotalDuration
    from CurrentPlace,
    PreviousPlaces
    where PreviousPlaces.PlaceID <= SequencesAnalysis.PlaceID
    group by CurrentPlace.RowID
```

Comment: i still dont get it. am sorry still new to SQL learner as student